# how to change value based on criteria pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a following problem. I have this df:

```py
d = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'value': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to have a new column where `value` will be 1 if in any other cases it is also 1. See desired output:

```py
d = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'value': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 'newvalue': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How can I do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need set `0,1` by condition - here at least one `1` use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for mask and casting to `integers` for `True, False` to `1,0` map:

```
df['newvalue'] = df['value'].eq(1).groupby(df['id']).transform('any').astype(int)
```

Alternative:

```
df['newvalue'] = df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['value'].eq(1), 'id']).astype(int)
```

Or if only `0,1` values is possible simplify solution for new column by maximal values per groups:

```
df['newvalue'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('max')
print (df)
   id  value  newvalue
0   1      0         1
1   1      1         1
2   2      0         0
3   2      0         0
4   3      1         1
```